# How do I initialize a final field in constructor's body?

Tags: dart

Basically, that's what I'm trying to do:

```dart
  ClassName
  {
    final OtherClass field;

    ClassName()
    {
      field = new OtherClass(this);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's not possible to assign a final field in a constructor body. The final field needs to be assigned before the constructor body, in the initializer list or on declaration:

```dart
class ClassName
{
    final OtherClass field = new OtherClass(); // Here

    ClassName()
        : field = new OtherClass() // or here 
    {
     
    }
}
```

As you can't use `this` in the initializer list or on the declaration, you can't do what you plan to do.

Comment: How do you set multiple final fields?

Comment: Separate them by commas.

Comment: what to do if we have two final fields an the second one depends on the first one?

Comment: @forgemo, then you have to set that inside a function body or make the first one static.

Comment: What if you have four final fields that are nested depended on each other? @ThinkDigital

Comment: @Sondre Sørbye, then you MAY be interested in restructuring it, because you can only assign in the initializer list all at once, not in order, so you can't evaluate arg1 and then use its value to evaluate arg2.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind this ? final fields can start to be very weird to setup..

Comment: Damn that's neat

Answer (score 23):

**With null safety**, you can initialize a `final` field in different ways:

- At declaration:

  ```dart
  class Foo{
    final int bar = 1;
  }
  ```
- In constructor parameter (initializing formal).

  ```
  class Foo {
    final int bar;

    // Initializing in constructor parameter.
    Foo(this.bar);
  }
  ```
- In the initializer list.

  ```
  class Foo {
    final int bar;

    // Initializer list
    Foo() : bar = 1;
  }
  ```
- Combination of above two.

  ```
  class Foo {
    final int bar;

    Foo(int value) : bar = value;
  }
  ```
- Use `late` keyword for lazy initialization.

  ```dart
  class Foo {
    late final int bar; // Initialize it later, maybe in a method
  }
  ```

Comment: one more way is using 'factory' constructor: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors

Comment: @vietstone Thanks but a `factory` constructor basically delegates the initialization to one of the concrete constructors.

Answer (score 3):

Since Dart 2.12 it is possible by using **late** keyword.
The code below prints 5:

```
class ClassName
  {
    final int var1 = 5;
    late final OtherClass field;

    ClassName()
    {
      field = new OtherClass(this);
    }
  }

class OtherClass {
  OtherClass(ClassName object) {
    print(object.var1);
  }
}

void main() {
  final object = ClassName();
}
```

Please see [this](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables) and the following sections

Comment: yes. but there are no way to check if 'field' is initialized or not.

Comment: @VladyslavUlianytskyi `try { print(object.field); } on LateInitializationError catch (e) { print(e); }`